# Applying Biot-Savart to a circular loop along central axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I'm trying to understand the solution to the magnetic field of a circular loop along its central axis. The solution I'm looking at is page 9 of this document: http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys270/Jenkins/LectureChapter33pt2.PDF

What I'm confused about is when they break the dB vector into two components, a y component and an x component. I agree that this is possible given that the current vector ds is entirely along the z axis. The problem is that as we sum around the loop, ds is not always along the z axis, so that I don't believe that dB will only have a y and x component, but will also have a z component so that one couldn't say that $dB_x$ = $dB\frac{R}{r}$ as they do in the solution. Am I wrong that dB is not always breakable into an x and y component? If I am correct, then why does the solution still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that those notes could have been written better.

The division of $d\textbf{B}$ into $y$ and $x$ components is only valid for the $d\textbf{s}$ as shown at the top of the loop.  At other locations, there will be a non-zero $z$ component to $d\textbf{B}$.

However, when the integration is done, there will be no net $z$ component, just like there will be no net $y$ component:  by symmetry, both those integrals will be zero.  The only non-zero component is in the $x$ direction.

Comment: The problem is that you can't say that the angle from the x axis to dB + the angle from dB to the y axis is 90 degrees and use the geometry of the big right triangle do compute the x component if there is a z component, so everything falls apart.

Comment: Just to see if we are on the same page, would you agree that it works for the $ds$ shown where the $z$ component of $dB$ is zero?

Comment: Yes I do agree! All I am saying is that for any ds where dB has 3 components, you can't use that simple trig to argue that the x-component is dB$\frac{R}{r}$. But, it has to be true if we are to sum over the circle. I'd like to see a picture showing how it still works when there are 3 components.

Comment: Very good.  The next step is to look at the symmetry.  Pick any angle.  The y and z components will be different for that angle.  By symmetry, however, the x-component will be the same regardless of angle.

Comment: Alternatively, pick any angle.  Then, create custom $y$ and $z$ axes aligned with that angle.  Call them, if you like, $y'$ and $z'$.  Compute the $x$-component of $B$ for these new axes using the same method as in the notes.  The result will be that the x-component does not depend on angle.

Comment: As for the symmetry argument, I'm visualizing B being perpendicular to the vector going from the circle to the point along the axis, as we keep changing this vector, we rotate it around in a circle, hence so does the vector B, but this is a circle in the y-z plane, hence B traces out a circle in the y-z plane and does not have a variable x component. Is that the kind of argument you were thinking of? I think it works! I come from math, and am not used to these kinds of non-rigorous arguments, but I'm growing quite fond of this kind of thinking.

Comment: Yes, you got it.